# Why doesn't double.class equal java.lang.Double.class?

Tags: java, class, primitive

Since the primitive double is represented with the java.lang.Double class, shouldn't double.class equal java.lang.Double.class?
(This of course also happens on other primitive types too)

```
System.out.println(double.class == Double.class);
```

Output:

```
Result: false
```

Comment: they're different class literals

Comment: `java.lang.Double` wraps/boxes a `double`, but it’s not the same.

Comment: @Trojaner Because these are different types that don’t behave the same way. For example, you cannot define a `List<double>`, but you can define a `List<Double>`.

Comment: (Same reason as a `double` is not a `Double`.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`Double.class` is the class object corresponding to the wrapper type `Double`. `double` is actually not a class, but `double.class` is the object used in reflection to indicate that an argument or return type has primitive type `double`.

Answer (score 4):

They are two distinct instances of `Class<Double>`. This doesn't normally happen (for ordinary objects), but for wrapper classes, that's exactly the way to distinguish between fields of the primitive type and the wrapper type in reflection.

Answer (score 3):

`double` is a primitive type, `Double` is a class type. There is a property on the `Double` class called `TYPE`:

For example `System.out.println(double.class == Double.TYPE);` prints true.